# How can I reload or update a new CA.pem file into the existing SSL CTX avoiding X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table exception

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have an established SSL connection. My context is loaded with `trustchain.pem` file which contains all the CA info.
During runtime, I am adding a new `CA.pem`
When this addition is made the existing `rustchain.pem` is reloaded and the new file is taken into its list.
Now if I add the new `trustchain.pem` file into the `SSL_CTX` using SSL API `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CAFile,CAPath)`
I receive:

```
Error Exception occurred message is error:0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table
```

and the existing connections are terminated.

How can I do this update without duplication?
Usually what happens if same .PEM file with CA list is loaded more than once using SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()